# Cannot implicitly convert String[] to string in case

Tags: c#

Obligatory I'm new to C# and am working on a large project for work and have run into a wall google can't seem to help me solve.

I understand that case's need to be constant and I am using a variable to declare a case but I can't seem to find the right way to correct the issue.

I am using the code to determine whether or not to send an order message to a market.

The defined variable

```
private string[] m_oKeys = new string[1];
```

The switch with the issue

```
        public void m_ts_OrderAdded(object sender, OrderAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        string key = e.Order.SiteOrderKey;
        switch (key)
        {
            case m_oKeys[1]:
                m_oObject = new e.Order();
                m_oKeys = new e.Order.SiteOrderKey();
                m_InFlight = new (false);
                break;
            case m_oKeys[]:
                m_oObject[] = e.Order;
                m_oKeys(1) = e.Order.SiteOrderKey;
                m_InFlight(1) = false;
                break;
            default:
                break;
                //handle order not found...
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `case m_oKeys[]` intended to match given there is no index specified ...?

Comment: Well, as you've already pointed out, the literals used in the case statements need to be constants. As such the only syntax you're allowed to use are constant literals, such as `case "key1":`. You can't use a variable here. Instead write out the switch-statement as a series of `if`-statements. Also, what is this supposed to match? `case m_oKeys[]:` <-- no index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined the array to contain a single string.

```
private string[] m_oKeys = new string[1];
```

So you can only reference the first element `m_oKeys[0]`.  As others have said, you must use constants for the `case` label.  Maybe `if-else` will work better for you.

```
public void m_ts_OrderAdded(object sender, OrderAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        string key = e.Order.SiteOrderKey;
        if (key == m_oKeys[0])
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I may have tried to get overly complex using the switch logic. Using if and else if statements is a much better idea. Thank you!